# How to pass container (IServiceProvider) to be available in business classes?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-standard, webapi

I have WebAPI (.NET 5) project that hosts services to be called from other (web) applications.
And, I would like to use Dependency Injection to get some service classes inside of my business objects.

Naturally, all calls to my project are going through Controllers that can receive IServiceProvider which will allow me to GetRequiredService().

All is good inside of the controller instance. But some/many of my business methods are not created by the Dependency Injection engine and as a result, I don't have access to the service provider and the only way to get data from the DI is to pass the instance of IServiceProvider manually to required business objects. Obviously, that will add up excessive code which will reduce readability.

What can I do to avoid passing the instance of IServiceProvider to my business objects and still be able to access it?

One solution I see is to create a static global object (_globalServiceProvider), but I'm afraid this will ruin the whole idea.

Anyone can recommend a better solution?

Comment: Put the service classes in a class library and share that library in all projects.

Comment: How can I get a singleton-type instance of a particular service? Clearly, I can make a static getter of a global instance of the service... but this does not feel right to me.

Comment: Register it in startup.cs like you would do for a service class in the native app. It will just have a different namespace. If I'm following you correctly.

Comment: But how can I access it deep inside of the business logic?

Comment: For DI you have three options: constructor injection (preferred), service locator (IServiceCollection/IHttpContextAccessor), or factory. If you can't use the constructor and you don't want to pass in the IServiceCollection or the HttpContextAccessor then create a factory just to new up the classes.